# Any Android ibeacon based open source project/libaries

Tags: android, sdk, ibeacon-android

Guys I am looking for direction to start for Android based iBeacon projects.

Any inputs for path ahead are welcome.

Comment: check this https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library

Comment: Estimote has a pretty good SDK. It is aimed at their products, but should work with other beacons too.

Comment: @njzk2 Note that Estimote themselves claim otherwise "the Estimote SDK works with and discovers only Estimote Beacons." here: https://community.estimote.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202653926-Interaction-with-other-manufacturers-iBeacons

Comment: @DannyA: my understanding when I read the documentation was that you could filter beacons by manufacturers, by high and low id, and all sort of stuff. I would find it pretty discouraging if they had made an SDK that works only for their products. (Almost as discouraging as the stickers, which have been in pre-order since last october)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend having a look at the [AltBeacon](http://altbeacon.org) library. Also, you don't want to confuse bluetooth low energy beacon functionality with the Apple branded term iBeacon! You can even test your beacon code if you have 2 Android devices. One can act as beacon transmitter, one can act as beacon scanner...